# Height of Textfields in tabular enviroment

Tags: tables, hyperref, height, forms, textfield

I am using lualatex to make a form with aligned input fields. I want a single line for Name and four lines for Address. This is my working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%Supress Label Printing
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
    \leavevmode#2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Name: & \TextField[width=0.5 \linewidth, height=10pt, borderwidth=0pt]{Name}\\
            Address: & \TextField[width=0.5 \linewidth, multiline=true, borderwidth=0pt, height=0pt]{Address}\\[40pt]
        \end{tabular}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This Produces:

[image: output]

I want a little separation between the Textfields so that it is clear that they are separate. But it seems that the Textfields just take up whatever space is available in the table. How can I achieve this?
I have also set the height for the second Field to 0pt otherwise the Address: label isn't top aligned. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!